# How do I create an index variable for unique values of another variable?

Tags: r

I would like to create a new variable which indexes the value of another variable. The new column starts from 1 as below. Thanks.

```
  ColumnIHave ColumnIWant
            A           1
            A           1
            A           1
            B           2
            B           2
            B           2
            C           3
            C           3
            C           3
```

Comment: `match()` ? have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your data to factor and then numeric using `dplyr`.

With pipes, the code would read like this:

`tbl1 %>% mutate(ColumnIWant = ColumnIHave %>% as.factor() %>% as.numeric())`

If you're not familiar with pipes and are more familiar with functions in other programming languages, the non-piped version is below.

```r
tbl1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "ColumnIHave 
A
A
A
B
B
B
C
C
C")
library(dplyr)
mutate(tbl1, ColumnIWant = as.numeric(as.factor(ColumnIHave)))
#>   ColumnIHave ColumnIWant
#> 1           A           1
#> 2           A           1
#> 3           A           1
#> 4           B           2
#> 5           B           2
#> 6           B           2
#> 7           C           3
#> 8           C           3
#> 9           C           3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

One option using `data.table`:

Data:

```
DT <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "ColumnIHave 
A
A
A
B
B
B
C
C
C")
```

Create column:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DT)
DT[, ColumnIWant:= .GRP, by = ColumnIHave]
DT
```

Result:

```
   ColumnIHave ColumnIWant
1:           A     1
2:           A     1
3:           A     1
4:           B     2
5:           B     2
6:           B     2
7:           C     3
8:           C     3
9:           C     3
```